# How to turn a file into 2D numpy array conditionally?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file with the format of

```
2,3: true
3,5: false
4,2: true
```

How can I turn rows with `true` into a 2D numpy array of

```
[[2,3],[4,2]]
```

I tried `numpy.genfromtxt`, but how can I apply the condition and limit the read rows to the first two sets of digit?

Comment: How big is your file? Just process each line sequentially?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It's quite big (millions of row). I tried `for` loop for each line, but I hoped to find a better solution performance wise.

Comment: It don't think it is reasonable to expect something builtin that could handle arbitrary file structures. You could chunk your file and run some multiprocessing code but that's about it.

Comment: I'd guess that the fastest solution will turn out to be reading a largish chunk into a Nx3 array, then doing something like `arr[arr[:,2]==1][:,:2]`, will turn out to be the fastest thing you can do without writing some Cython or C code to custom parse the lines.

Comment: But meanwhile, looping ~10M times in Python instead of Numpy is slow—but we're talking "slow" as in "wastes dozens of milliseconds". That's a horrible bottleneck in some code that's applying a 50ns `+` to each element, but probably doesn't matter at all in some code that's reading off the disk. (Decoding bytes to text, on the other hand, _could_ be relevant, so I'd use binary mode.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple million rows of ints is probably not too big to load into a NumPy array all at once (depending on your computer's available RAM). So you might be able to generate the desired array by first loading the full numeric array, and then loading the boolean mask:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data', delimiter=',', usecols=[0,1], comments=':', dtype=int)
mask = np.genfromtxt('data', delimiter=' ', usecols=[1], dtype=str) == 'true'
result = data[mask]
```

yields

```
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 2]])
```

I used two calls to `np.genfromtxt` to get around the problem of the data file having two different delimiters (i.e. commas and spaces).

<strike>Although loading the entire array may seem wasteful, it is much faster than parsing the file line-by-line (provided you have enough memory to do so.)</strike>

It turns out -- [thanks to hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143638/how-to-turn-a-file-into-2d-numpy-array-conditionally/50143862?noredirect=1#comment87306067_50143862) for motivating me to test -- that a simple `for-loop` is much faster:

For example, with this setup:

```
import numpy as np

def make_data(N=10**6):
    data = np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 2))
    mask = np.array(['true', 'false'])[np.random.randint(2, size=N)]
    with open('data', 'w') as f:
        for row, maski in zip(data, mask):
            f.write('{},{}: {}\n'.format(row[0], row[1], maski))

def using_genfromtxt():
    data = np.genfromtxt('data', delimiter=',', usecols=[0,1], comments=':', dtype=int)
    mask = np.genfromtxt('data', delimiter=' ', usecols=[1], dtype=str) == 'true'
    result = data[mask]
    return result

def using_readline():
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144016/190597 (hpaulj)
    """
    def foo1(f):
        for line in f:
            x,y = line.split(':')
            if y.strip()=='true':
                yield x.split(',')
    with open('data', 'r') as f:
        return np.array(list(foo1(f)), dtype=int)

make_data()
```

we can use IPython to benchmark the speed of `using_genfromtxt` vs `using_readline`:

```
In [152]: %timeit using_genfromtxt()
1 loop, best of 3: 8.8 s per loop

In [171]: %timeit using_readline()
1 loop, best of 3: 861 ms per loop
```

So a simple `for-loop` is actually 10x faster.

Comment: Since `genfromtxt` uses `readline`, and you have to read all the lines one way or other, I doubt if there's much time difference in various processing strategies.  It's the mix of delimiters that makes this double read attractive.

Comment: @hpaulj: You're right and [your parsing strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144016/190597) is much faster. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, that handles both the mixed delimiters and the conditionality is to pass the file through a filter function.

Define a generator that takes a file, or anything that iterates on lines, and returns a filtered set of strings:

```
def foo(f):
    for line in f:
        x,y = line.split(':')
        if y.strip()=='true':
            yield x
```

Using a text standin for a file:

```
In [55]: txt='''2,3: true
    ...: 3,5: false
    ...: 4,2: true
    ...: 2,3: true
    ...: 3,5: false
    ...: 4,2: true'''
```

The generator returns strings as in:

```
In [56]: list(foo(txt.splitlines()))
Out[56]: ['2,3', '4,2', '2,3', '4,2']
```

`genfromtxt` readily turns such a feed into an array:

```
In [57]: np.genfromtxt(foo(txt.splitlines()),delimiter=',', dtype=int)
Out[57]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 2]])
```

`genfromtxt` iterates of a file in Python, so the use of `foo` shouldn't change its speed much.

`pandas` has a good csv reader, but the faster compiled version doesn't have as many bells and whistles as the Python one.

---

Or I could skip `genfromtxt` entirely:

```
def foo1(f):
    for line in f:
        x,y = line.split(':')
        if y.strip()=='true':
            yield x.split(',')

In [63]: np.array(list(foo1(txt.splitlines())), dtype=int)
Out[63]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 2]])
```

The file format, after selecting rows, is simple enough that `np.array` can handle it, and do the string to integer conversion directly.